# Python: Pandas Dataframe Using Wildcard to Find String in Column and Keep Row

Tags: python, string, dataframe, find, wildcard

I have a pandas data frame.  Below is a sample table.

```
Event   Text
A       something/AWAIT hello          
B       la de la
C       AWAITING SHIP
D       yes NO AWAIT
```

I want to only keep rows that contain some form of the word AWAIT in the Text column.  Below is my desired table:

```
Event   Text
A       something/AWAIT hello          
C       AWAITING SHIP
D       yes NO AWAIT
```

Below is the code I tried to capture strings that contain AWAIT in all possible circumstances.

```
df_STH001_2 = df_STH001[df_STH001['Text'].str.contains("?AWAIT?") == True]
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 0
```

Comment: just remove question marks...

Comment: does that capture when it says something/AWAIT though?

Comment: it's faster to try it than to write a comment ;-)

Comment: ah you're right! it worked, thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Series.str.contains(pat, case=True, flags=0, na=nan, regex=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) per default treats `pat` as a RegEx.

The question mark (`?`) makes the *preceding* token in the regular expression optional, hence the error message.

```
In [178]: d[d['Text'].str.contains('AWAIT')]
Out[178]:
  Event                   Text
0     A  something/AWAIT hello
2     C          AWAITING SHIP
3     D           yes NO AWAIT
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the `match` method:

```
df[df.column.str.match('some_string')]
```